# Why do the results of my "ffmpeg -ss -to" split have audio but no video?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to split clips into short intervals (that I am reading in from a csv) using ffmpeg. The commands that I'm using look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.030000 -to 00:00:02.030000   
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c copy new_filename.mp4
```

This successfully splits the parent mp4 into many smaller mp4s, but the smaller files lose some or all of their video. Most of them end up being just audio. Some have video - but only for about half of the clip (the rest is black). The audio is always there. Any ideas why this might be happening?

A couple notes: I'm using ffmpeg 3.0.2. Also, I am creating this command as a Python list and running it with the following call

```
subprocess.run(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Does one of the following help? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/how-to-force-ffmpeg-to-insert-keyframe-at-first-frame-when-downsampling-a-framer and https://superuser.com/questions/908280/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-keyframes-in-ffmpeg-for-dash

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer it won't - the OP is streamcopying. To the OP, if you change `-c copy` to `-c:a copy`, it will work.

Comment: -c copy will not work because there are no keyframes in that time range. Your must reencode.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks for your help and quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by comments from Mulvya and szatmary. Posting those as an answer to close out question.

> "The OP is streamcopying. To the OP, if you change -c copy to -c:a
>   copy, it will work." –Mulvya
>
> "-c copy will not work because there are no keyframes in that time
>   range. Your must reencode." –szatmary

The solution Mulvya suggested was to add a stream specifier. I did this, and got the result I was looking for. There's documentation here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1